# MVC Architecture in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

Can anyone one you provide me a sample application of iPhone which is based on MVC Architecture? If the program flow of App is provided in the documentation then that will be great! Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much any iPhone app example you get hold of will use MVC design! MVC is so cruical to iPhone development.

Here are a few examples of how the Cocoa touch framework uses MVC:

- UIViewController and subclasses (Controllers)
- UIView/UIResponder/UIControl and subclasses (Views)
- NSString/NSArray/NSDictionary/Core Data (Model)

Answer (score 1):

Take look at the [Lecture 1](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/131) from CS193p. You can also find the videos on iTunes U. Just search for CS193P.

And look at apple tutorial [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/01_Overview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH10-SW6)